# Static constructor is no longer run before Assembly Resolution in .NetCore (.Net6)

Tags: c#, .net-6.0

I am migrating huge, 32-bit, desktop (winforms) codebase from .NetFramework462 to .Net6. The code itself works well after migration when run from VisualStudio.
We have around 150 csprojs and some of the dlls are shared across multiple executables, so during installation we put shared assemblies in `C:\ProgramFiles (x86)\MyProgram\Assemblies` rather than copying each of them to each program's subfolder.

We have custom `MyAssemblyLoader` which correctly loads assemblies from our `Assemblies` folder if they're missing in application root folder. We register our assembly loader to handle `AssemblyResolve` event in static constructor of our program like this:

```
static class Program
    {
        private static MyAssemblyResolver _assemblyResolver = new MyAssemblyResolver();

        static Program()
        {
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += (sender, args) => _assemblyResolver.AssemblyResolve(args.Name);
        }
        
        // Main() and other code is here
    }
```

The problem is that when I build the program under .NetFramework462 and remove one of dependency dlls from `bin\Debug` folder it correctly loads it from `Assemblies` folder. I can set a breakpoint in static constructor and see that it is being called.
In same scenario in .Net6 I get `System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly'`  even before static constructor is run. The exception has no stack trace and it doesn't enter static constructor at all, like the exception is thrown even before it is called.

I tried to load some other assemblies which are not necessary for project to run from `Assemblies` folder with `MyAssembliesLoader` in .Net6 in Immediate window and it works fine.

Here are details about how it is referenced in csprojs (I believe it shouldn't matter for runtime resolver):
In .Net6 I have SDK csprojs with reference to missing dll via one of shared projects (dll is not directly referenced in csproj)

```
<ProjectReference Include="OneOfSharedProjects.csproj" />
```

and in `OneOfSharedProjects.csproj`

```
<ProjectReference Include="MissingDLL.csproj" />
```

While in .NetFramework462 the project is directly referenced

```
    <ProjectReference Include="MissingDLL.csproj">
      <Project>{12345678-FFBC-419B-AEAB-3A9B1A4D4847}</Project>
      <Name>MissingDLL</Name>
    </ProjectReference>
```

`Assemblies` folder path is resolved in runtime so I'd like to avoid hardcoding the path in config files.
How can I load referenced libraries from custom folder in .Net6?

PS:

- Our libraries are not being registered in GAC so that's not the case
- Moving `AssemblyResolve` assignment from static constructor to `Main()` doesn't help. The code behaves as before (exception before `Main()` is called)

Comment: AFAIK the `AppDomain` approach is deprecated in .Net Core. You have to use the `AssemblyLoadContext`. For an example take a look at https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1194332/Resolving-Assemblies-in-NET-Core

Comment: It is a very brittle scheme.  Multiple failure modes, the most obvious one is in the snippet that we can see.  It has no static fields and you'd never create an instance of the class, so no need to run the static constructor.

Comment: @HansPassant Program class has static `Main()` method below which is the entry point of app and this static constructor used to be called before `Main()` was called back in .NetFramework462

Comment: [*It is called automatically before the first instance is created or any static members are referenced.*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-constructors).  So no, Main() is not enough to ensure the static constructor runs.  That net462 behaved differently might have something to do with [this](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/13036).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the issue. It looks like the problem was in reference to class from missing library **directly** in `Main()` method.
Let's assume that class `C` is in missing library.
Having Main like this:

```
class Program
{
    static Program()
    {
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += (s, e) => _assemblyResolver.AssemblyResolve(e.Name);
    }
    static void Main()
    {    
        C c = new C();
        ApplicationConfiguration.Initialize();
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
}
```

won't work because .Net6 tries to load library containing `C` definition before assembly resolver is added as event handler. But if class from missing library is not used directly, the problem is gone. Example:

```
class Program
{
    static Program()
    {
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += (s, e) => _assemblyResolver.AssemblyResolve(e.Name);
    }
    static void Main()
    {
        NewMethod();
        ApplicationConfiguration.Initialize();
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
    private static void NewMethod()
    {
        C c = new C();
    }
}
```

Now even if dll is moved somewhere else where AssemblyResolver can find it, the code will work just fine

Comment: This behavior has nearly always been in .net framework too. A method needs to be jitted before it starts execution and how would the jit work if it cannot load all the types first? You were lucky to have not hit it before.

Comment: The difference is that I could have static constructor which was called before `Main()` dependencies were loaded. My static constructor had nothing but event handler and comment that nothing else should be in this constructor. Now it looks like static constructor is actually run after `Main()` dependencies are loaded

Comment: I have edited my answer to make a point with static constructor more clear